# Windows service is installed and running but not functioning in Python

Tags: python, windows-services

I had written a windows service in python and able to install and run it properly. But the main functionality (showing icon on windows system's tray) is not working. I tried to debug by writing some of the print() functions inside every functions like `print('inside constructor'), print('inside SvcDoRun'), print('inside SvcDoStop'), print('inside main'), etc.` and the shoking thing is that even the constructor is not getting invoked, nothing from the above print() methods is getting printed only `print('hello world')` is getting executed. I am trying to figure it out for last 2-3 days but not able to understand the issue. I am not able to proceede further because of this issue.

```
import sys
import win32event
import win32service
import servicemanager
import win32serviceutil

from PIL import Image
from pystray import Icon


class EdiqueService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'EdiqueService_PY'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'EdiqueService_PY'
    _svc_description_ = 'EdiqueService_PY description'

    print('hello world')

    def __init__(self, args):
        print('inside constructor')
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        print('inside SvcStop')
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        print('inside SvcDoRun')
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))
        self.main()

    def create_system_tray_icon(self):
        image = Image.open("active.png")
        icon = Icon("name", image, "Title")
        return icon

    def main(self):
        print('inside main')
        icon = self.create_system_tray_icon()
        icon.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(EdiqueService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(EdiqueService)
```

Please provide some solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know servicemanager package, but are you not supposed to put in the EdiqueService instance? Seems Like the method doesn't initialise your class